# Is there a way of modify lists with this criterion in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, set, combinations

Let's say we have an ordered set of elements `[a, b]`:

Initial set

```
[[1,5], [2,5], [3,5], [3,6], [4,5]]
```

Since I am interested in the **sets being 4 elements**, and I see that elements 2 and 3 have the same value of `a`, I would like to know how to write a program that starts from the initial set and does the following:

Set 1

```
[[1,5], [2,5], [3,5], [4,5]]
```

Set 2

```
[[1,5], [2,5], [3,6], [4,5]]
```

If for example the initial set were:

```
[[1,5], [2,5], [3,5], [3,6], [4,5], [4,6]]
```

The program should return:

```
[[1,5], [2,5], [3,5], [4,5]]
[[1,5], [2,5], [3,5], [4,6]]
[[1,5], [2,5], [3,6], [4,5]]
[[1,5], [2,5], [3,6], [4,6]]
```

Is there a way in python to do this? I have tried to use the `combinations` and `permutations` module but it seems to me that it is excessive for the simplicity of the task.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you want sets or lists?

Comment: What should the output be for `[[1,5], [2,5], [1,4], [3,6], [4,5], [4,6]]`?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, your input is not ordered

Comment: @joostblack: Good call. Thanks

Comment: @inspectorG4dget well, lets say you meant Input =` [[1,4], [1,5], [2,5], [3,6], [4,5], [4,6` in this case the output should be : `[[1,4], [1,5], [2,5], [3,6], [4,5]]`List2 = `[[1,4], [1,5], [2,5], [3,6], [4,6]]`. It should convert the input in lists of 4 elements changing the ones which have the element[0] value repeated in the input. Don`t know if I'm explaining myself correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by first element, then get the `product`:

```
import collections, itertools

lst = [[1,5], [2,5], [3,5], [3,6], [4,5]]
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for x in lst:
    d[x[0]].append(x)

res = list(itertools.product(*d.values()))                                    
# [([1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 5], [4, 5]),
#  ([1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 6], [4, 5])]
```

If the list is sorted by the first element, you can also use `groupby` as shown in the other answer, and then get the `product of those:

```
from itertools import product, groupby                                  
for x in product(*(list(g) for k, g in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x[0]))): 
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
import operator


def groupify(L):  # create all the groupings
    answer = []
    for k,group in itertools.groupby(L, operator.itemgetter(0)):
        answer.append(list(group))
    return answer


def dfs(L, answer=None):  # depth first search algorithm
    if answer is None:
        answer = []
    if not L:
        yield answer

    else:
        for sub in L[0]:
            yield from dfs(L[1:], answer+[sub])


def main(L):  # do a DFS on the groupings
    for a in dfs(groupify(L)):
        print(a)
```

Testing:

```
In [188]: main([[1,5], [2,5], [3,5], [3,6], [4,5], [4,6]])                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[[1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 5], [4, 5]]
[[1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 5], [4, 6]]
[[1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 6], [4, 5]]
[[1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 6], [4, 6]]
```